# Почему алгоритм сортировки выбором выполняет столько же операций для поиска индекса в массиве, сколько и пузырьковый? Как это возможно?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Имеется два алгоритма, почему кол-во операций в переменных счетчиках count и count2 одинаковое, если алгоритмы разные?

И вообще правильно ли я написал алгоритм сортировки пузырьком?

```
const arr = [
  0, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 2, 9, 6, 4, 1, 7, -1, -5, 23, 6, 2, 35, 6, 3,
  32,
]

let count = 0
let count2 = 0

function bubbleSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] < array[i]) {
        let temp = array[j]
        array[j] = array[i]
        array[i] = temp
      }
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return array
}

// console.log('length', arr.length)
console.log(bubbleSort(arr)) // O(n*n)
console.log('bubble count = ', count)

function selectionSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let indexMin = i
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[j] < array[indexMin]) {
        indexMin = j
      }
      count2 += 1
    }
    let temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[indexMin]
    array[indexMin] = temp
  }
  return array
}

console.log(selectionSort(arr))
// console.log(arr.length) // O(n*n)
console.log(' count = ', count2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 

Уберём из `bubblesort` всё что не относится к счётчику:

```
function bubbleSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
}
```

Уберём из `selectionSort` всё что не относится к счётчику:

```
function selectionSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      count2 += 1
    }
  }
}
```

Удивление ещё не прошло? Вы считаете двумя способами одно и то же число. Называется оно [треугольным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

2.

Нет, это не пузырёк. В любом пузырьке местами меняются только соседние элементы. В вашем коде вы меняете далёкие друг от друга элементы.

Comment: Спасибо!!!
Вот с этим моментом немного запутался, сортировка пузырьком function bubbleSort реализована правильно?

Comment: Я тоже запутался. Сейчас поправил ответ. Ваш код - не пузырек.